lda uses sklearn visual analysis to report errors
When using the sklearn library for LDA visual analysis, the error 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names' is reported，But I have never used this attribute before. I used tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(). I don’t understand why I still report this error.
The relevant code is as follows
[enter image description hereenter image description here](https://enter image description here/QHN7B.png)
This error should generally be reported when using get_feature_names when outputting the topic name, but I did not use that attribute. I used tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), and the topic feature words were successfully displayed without an error. This attribute was not used elsewhere, no. Do you know why I keep reporting this error 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'
I tried changing sklearn to lda_model, and then the error message became No module named 'pyLDAvis.lda_model'enter image description here
Some people said that there was a problem with the sklearn version, and they also tried to reduce the version of pyLDAvis to 2.1.2, but the result remained unchanged.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
